# Automapper map Viewmodel to Model with same name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

Viewmodel

```
public string Personal_Data_Surname { get; set; }
public string FamilyMember_SurName { get; set; }
```

Entity class Applicant

```
public string SurName { get; set; }
```

Entity class FamilyMember

```
public string SurName { get; set; }
```

Automapper Config

```
        Mapper.Configuration.RecognizePrefixes("Personal_Data_");
        Mapper.CreateMap<ApplicationViewModel, Applicant>();

        Mapper.Configuration.RecognizePrefixes("FamilyMember_");
        Mapper.CreateMap<ApplicationViewModel, FamilyMember>();
```

Controller code mapping entities

```
Applicant applicant = Mapper.Map<ApplicationViewModel, Applicant>(vaModel);
FamilyMember familyMember = Mapper.Map<ApplicationViewModel, FamilyMember>(vaModel);
```

The problem is that it maps Personal_Data_Surname from the viewmodel to the Surname in entity class Applicant and FamilyMember. Is it possible to specify a prefix for a specific type

Answer (score 0):

You have to customize your mapping using `ForMemeber` method, with the `MapFrom` option method, for sample:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ApplicationViewModel, Applicant>()
       .ForMember(viewModel => viewModel.Personal_Data_Surname, 
                  opt => opt.MapFrom(entity => entity.SurName));
```

Then, AutoMapper will map the `Personal_Data_Surname` viewModel's property to `SurName` entity's property. Do it to another entities.